# How to use System.Management.Automation for project target windows 8.1?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a windows 8.1 App, that needs to execute a powershell script. I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/):

It sais to: *add a project reference to the System.Management.Automation assembly*

But NuGet Console says: **Install-Package : Could not install package 'System.Management.Automation 6.1.7601.17515'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Windows,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content 
files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.**

Is there any other way to execute a powershell script within a windows 8.1 app? Help is very appreciated.